# iMac keyboard for programming. Is that comfortable or I should buy another one?

Tags: keyboard, imac, development

I'm planning to buy an iMac next month. I'm a software developer. I usually use the Microsoft Keyboard for my programming tasks, It has a great ergonomics. I tried iMac's keyboard in the store but didn't get a chance to sit down and use it for an hour or so to understand if that works for me. Anyone is using it for heavy programming and can tell me if that is comfortable for hours of coding ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use it everyday for my programming job. The thing I like the most about it is that the keys are low profile, so it's easy to glide your fingers across. That said, I have used a mac keyboard for the last 5 years, so I got used to it. You can only try to see if it fits you.

Comment: +1 I use mine all the time too. Whenever I go back to a "standard" keyboard, it feels like using an old-fashioned typewriter with the long key travel ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I use the built in keyboard in my MBP which is comparable to the usb keyboard that comes with iMacs. I love it, and I agree that now any "regular" keyboards feel large and typewriter-y. (For lack of a better word). I do code on a daily basis and I find this keyboard the most comfortable one I have used.

Hope This Helps.